# RECORRER TEXTO EN LCD EN ENSAMBLADOR

Tags: ensamblador, asm, pic

Estoy haciendo un código en ensamblador en un PIC16F877A y programé un LCD con un teclado matricial 4x3 y necesito que al final apretando la tecla # recorra todo el texto a la derecha pero no lo logro :( Ayuda por favor[image: Conexiones en SIMULIDE]

Aqui está parte de mi código

```
NUMEROENTER; PARA RECORRER A LA DERECHA
    BTFSC PORTD,1
    GOTO NUMEROENTER
    MOVLW B'000101'; MOVER TODO EL TEXTO A LA DERECHA 
    MOVWF PORTB
    BSF PORTA,0;RS EN UNO 
    BSF PORTA,1; SALIDA 
    CALL RETARDO
    BSF PORTA,1;CERRAMOS EN 0
    BSF PORTA,0;
    RETURN
```